# CLion not recognizing library functions with OpenGL mingw64

Tags: opengl, clion, mingw-w64

I've been trying to run sample code on Clion but I get warnings with the library functions:
`#include <math.h> #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h>`
telling me to change to  etc. When I run it, I get errors like this:

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\brewe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfqeelO.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9cb): undefined reference to `__imp_glutMainLoop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Is there something wrong with my CMakeLists? I followed a tutorial religiously on how to download everything so I'm pretty sure I am not missing any downloads. I honestly don't know what the problem is. This is my CMakeLists for reference:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(hw1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(hw1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hw1 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries({GLUT_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(hw1 -lopengl32 -g -lfreeglut)
```

If you have any suggestions, please help.